# error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘__fpclassify’

Tags: c, compilar, math

Tengo un error al compilar un programa, concretamente en la parte de los *include*:

```
En el fichero incluido desde /usr/include/math.h:296,
                 desde commands.c:105:
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h:26:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘__fpclassify’
   26 | __MATHDECL_ALIAS (int, __fpclassify,, (_Mdouble_ __value), fpclassify)
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

En el archivo ***/usr/include/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h*** tengo lo siguiente:

```
/* Classify given number.  */
__MATHDECL_ALIAS (int, __fpclassify,, (_Mdouble_ __value), fpclassify)
     __attribute__ ((__const__));
```

¿Será que no puede interpretar las dos comas que están juntas o es que no permite argumentos que solo sean un tipo de dato, como lo es `int`?

¿Cómo soluciono esto?

Comment: Sin un ejemplo con código va a estar complicado darte una respueta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es incluir `math.h` al inicio de `mathcalls-helper-functions.h`:

```
#include <math.h>

/* Classify given number.  */
__MATHDECL_ALIAS (int, __fpclassify,, (_Mdouble_ __value), fpclassify) __attribute__ ((__const__));
```